# Windows 7 touchscreen keyboard in a WPF app

Tags: wpf, windows-7, keyboard, multi-touch

I'm building a .NET 3.5 sp1 WPF app for use on Windows 7 - is there a way to place the touchscreen keyboard in my application?

NOTE: In contrast to other similar questions I'm not looking to embed the keyboard in my app, I just want to start the keyboard and use it for text entry.

Comment: If you're not embedding it in your application, then you're intending to just start an external application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Will said...just start the process.

```
System.Process.Start("osk")
```

Comment: You can't call the default (64bit) osk.exe from a 32bit application, so make sure you compile your app for x64.

Answer (score 0):

Create a desktop shortcut to a batch file that starts both your application and the Windows on-screen keyboard?